# PHP all combinations into array

Tags: php

Let's say I have two variables, strings converted to arrays

```
$VAR_1 = '1-1:2-1';
$VAR_1 = Explode(':', $VAR_1);

$VAR_2 = '3-1:4-1:2-2:2-3:2-4';
$VAR_2 = Explode(':', $VAR_2);
```

Now I want 'all' combinations of VAR_1 and VAR_2 mixed set into a new array $COMB

But at least 1, or both variable(s) of VAR_1 must be in the new array, and the combined string must consists of 5 variables.

I need ALL combinations, also duplicate, but which are in a different order.

How to achieve this ?

Scenario: Poker Game (VAR_1 = player cards (color - number) VAR_2 = table cards)

Comment: What will be your desire output array ?

Comment: something like: COMB[] = '1-1:3-1:4-1:5-1:6-1' if one from VAR_1 has been selected and 4 from VAR_2 have been selected

Comment: `Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration`. You should stick to that.

Comment: explode() correct, Explode() incorrect ? why it always works

Comment: explode() is a function but other programmer will expect Explode to be a class since it starts with capital letter, it will not affect the functionality but it confuses other people

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
 $array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
 $array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
 $result = $array1 + $array2;
 var_dump($result);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create an array of all 7 variables, using simple

```
$arr3 = $arr1 + $arr2;
```

or

```
$arr3 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

Then, you need to select 5-element groups, that means 2 element will always be skipped out, these 2 elements will have indexes $i and $j, making 2 nested for cycles an excelent solution for this problem, here's an example:

```
$array = array("1-2", "1-5", "1-8", "3-4", "2-1", "2-2", "1-6");
$result = array(); //not sure if this line is nesseserly, but better be sure
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= 7; $j++) {
        $buffer = array(); //this is nesseserly
        for ($k = 0; $k < 7; $k++) {
            if ($k == $i || $k == $j) {
                continue;
            }
            $buffer[] = $array[$k]; //add to end
        }
        $result[] = $buffer; //add to end
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

This works wine for me, tested.

Answer (score -1):

Use array_merge()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$a = array("a", "b", "c");
$b = array("g", "a", "f");
$c = array_merge($a, $b);
var_dump($c); //array("a", "b", "c", "g", "a", "f");
```

Comment: He wants the combination not merging arrays